# Android "meen" and "noon" arabic language problems

Tags: android, arabic

I have tried Farsi and arabicreshaper libraries, but both have some issues regarding "meen" and "noon" when tashkeel exists, anyone solved this issue?

this is the issue:

http://postimg.org/image/8wjlnhvqt/

Answer (score 0):

i have used this improved library , where it worked better:

https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper/

then used the following code

```
ArabicUtilities aru=new ArabicUtilities();
aru.getArabicEnabledTextView(getApplicationContext(), tv);
tv.setText(aru.reshape("\n"+edit)+"\n");
```